# Using `useState` with Beautiful DND in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-beautiful-dnd

I've been following a guide to add beautiful dnd to my react app here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYZRRyukuIw&t=1s

Here is an array of exercises

```
const exercises = [
  {
    title: 'Abdominal Crunch',
    id: '4YRrftQysvE1Kz8XACtrq4',
    rest: ['30', '30', '30', '30', '30', '', '', '', '', ''],
    reps: ['5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '', '', '', '', ''],
    time: false
  },
  {
    title: 'Bicep curl',
    rest: ['30', '30', '30', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    reps: ['5', '5', '', '5', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    time: false
  }
];
```

And I'm mapping through the exercises

```
...

  return (
    <section>
      <div>
        <DragDropContext onDragEnd={(result) => console.log(result)}>
          <Droppable droppableId="items">
            {(provided, snapshot) => {
              return (
                <div
                  className="exercises"
                  {...provided.droppableProps}
                  ref={provided.innerRef}
                >
                  {exercises.map((exercise, index) => {
                    return (
                      <Draggable
                        key={exercise.id}
                        draggableId={exercise.id}
                        index={index}
                      >
                        {(provided, snapshot) => {
                          return (
                            <div
                              className="exercise__item"
                              {...provided.draggableProps}
                              {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                              å
                              ref={provided.innerRef}
                              style={{
                                userSelect: "none",
                                ...provided.draggableProps.style,
                              }}
                            >
                              {exercise} 
                            </div>
                          );
                        }}
                      </Draggable>
                    );
                  })}
                  {provided.placeholder}
                </div>
              );
            }}
          </Droppable>
        </DragDropContext>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default ExercisesList;
```

This is working perfectly but the problem I'm having is saving the state `onDragEnd`.

```
  const onDragEnd = (result) => {
     if(!result.destination) return;
   // Can I save the state in here?
  }
```

Using the existing state I have already configured?

```
  const fieldValue = props.sdk.field.getValue();
  const [exercises, setExercises] = useState(fieldValue || []);
```

Comment: That should not be a problem, but can ou put that in a sandbox so we can see your whole code?

Comment: Sure, there's quite a bit of debug in there but here's a gist link. Thanks -https://gist.github.com/imshuffling/b3f027f6cf37c318d37765354e5a12a0

Comment: So why not just use this: setExercises(prevExercises => {...return modifedValues})

Comment: OK, could you write that out for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the result object to receive the initial and final index of the item and reorder the array accordingly:

```
const onDragEnd = (result) => {
  if(!result.destination) return;
  setExercises(prevExercises => {
    const exercises = Array.from(prevExercises); // Create a new array to not mutate the previous one
    const [removed] =  exercises.splice(result.source.index, 1); // Removes the drag item from the array by using the start index
    exercises.splice(result.destination.index, 0, removed); // Inserts the moved item at its new position using the end index
    return exercises // Returns the reordered array to the hook to be saved
  })
}
```

I updated the names, @david-riches

Comment: OK thanks, I'm getting an error on that with `Cannot read property 'index' of undefined`

with this offending line. `const [removed] = result.splice(result.source.index, 1);`

Comment: Got it working, thanks for your help. Was missing  `const { source, destination } = result;` above setExercise, if you edit your original answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: Sry i had a wrong naming. Fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
  const onDragEnd = (result) => {
    if (!result.destination) return;
    const { source, destination } = result;
    setExercises((prevExercises) => {
      const result = Array.from(prevExercises); // Create a new array to not mutate the previous one
      const [removed] = result.splice(source.index, 1); // Removes the drag item from the array by using the start index
      result.splice(destination.index, 0, removed); // Inserts the moved item at its new position using the end index
      return result; // Returns the reordered array to the hook to be saved
    });
  };
```